# Border width was ignored

Tags: css, sass

Have an issue with border width.I have padding 11 and line-height 21px 11+21= 43 and have border 1px, height should be 43+2=45 but I have only 44.45

my border become 0.727(0.8 in simulation) and I don't understand why this happened. Outer div display: block;  and this input display: inline-block;

```css
.max-w-\[96px] {
  max-width: 96px;
}

.new-trade__input-group {
  display: block;
}

.input-text {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  --tw-boder-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(230 232 233 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(230 232 233 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right:  1rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 150%;
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(15 34 42 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-tav-c253 class="new-trade__input-group w-2/6"><input _ngcontent-tav-c253 type="text" placeholder="Days" onlynumbers class="input-text input-text--darken max-w-[96px] ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-is-disable="false">
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post images for text content, nor links to external code. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help people help you.